# Why won't my django queryset work?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to run a queryset with the value of the filter being the values inside a dictionary.

```
latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(zipcode__in=nearestzips.values())

print latest_entries
>>>TypeError: Cannot use a multi-field GeoValuesQuerySet as a filter value.
```

second attempt

```
latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(zipcode__in=nearestzips.values_list('code', flat=True))

print latest_entries
>>>ProgrammingError: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "cities_postalcode" HINT perhaps you meant to reference the table alias"u0"
```

How can I accomplish this?  Should I just take the extra step of creating a new list and appending the dictionary values into the list?  And then run the queryset on the list?  I'm not sure what to do.

EDIT:

when I print nearestzips I get:

```
[<PostalCode:97201>,<PostalCode:97202>]
```

BUT, when I print nearestzips.values(), I get:

```
[distance:0, code: 97201, name: Portland, subregion: Multnomah] etc.
```

Comment: I have no idea what that last error means.

Comment: I updated my question, I think I got confused because print nearestzips returns ONLY the Postal Codes, so I thought that's what the only values were in nearestzips, I still don't know what to do though.

Comment: `values()` returns list (actually an iterator) of dicts where the keys are the model's field names. `values_list()` returns an iterator of tuples instead of dicts.  `values_list(field, flat=True)` returns an iterator of single field's values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `nearestzips` is a subclass of the `QuerySet` which is lost some compatibility. Try to convert `values_list()` to the simple python list:

```
zip_codes = list(nearestzips.values_list('code', flat=True))
latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(zipcode__in=zip_codes)
```

Comment: Okay this is what I'm going to do, but when I print zip_codes I get [u'97202, u'97206', u'97214', u'97215', u'97239']  I'm guessing I have to strip the u out of there first otherwise I don't think the queryset will work.

Comment: When you print `zip_codes` then the `__repr()__` method called and zip_codes `ValuesQuerySet` is printed like a regular list. But this is not a list so you have to convert it with the `list()` call. And no, you don't need to strip `u` - this is just indicator, that values in the list are unicode strings.